# javascript element to display name of person from file

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I am reading a javascript tutorial and trying to figure out how to have my page show the name of a person as well as his birthday in this day in history

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Today is <br/>");
        document.write(showDate());
        document.write("Born Today <br/>");
        var name = "mName";
        document.write(dayNumber());
        var day = "showBirthDay";
        document.write(day);

        </script>

        </section>
```

I am not sure on how to link this code which is a html page to the function.js page.

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I assume function.js is a JS library file of some type. To link it to your HTML page add this line of code in between the < head> tags:

```
<script src="function.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have that sorry, this is in the header, the problem I am having is trying to get the javacsript to only pull from the function.js the appropriate days birthday

Comment: http://ipmcg.com/IT270/Tut10/CP4/functions.js   this is the page that the above javascript should be pulling from